# Как добавить участника в чат через telebot python?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

подскажите, есть ли у библиотеки telebot в python возможность добавлять участников в чаты/каналы?

Comment: Короткий ответ - нет.

Answer (score 0):

Нет. Ни `telebot`, ни `aiogram` не имеют такой возможности.

Возможно, вам следует использовать либо [`telethon`](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/stable/), либо [`pyrogram`](https://docs.pyrogram.org/).